# Prove that $2^d$ is not congruent to $1 \mod p^2$

Tags: divisibility, congruences

We have $p>2$ - prime number and we know that $2^n\equiv 1\mod p$ and $2^n$ is not congruent to $1 \mod p^2$ ($n$-natural number). Prove that $2^d$ is not congruent to $1 \mod p^2$ where order $2 = d \mod p$.

I will be grateful when someone tell me for what I have to start.

Comment: What does $n$ have to do with $d$?

Comment: If you use mathjax, it is easier to read (and to help): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don't know what $n$ does with d. It's in the command exercise.

Comment: Is d also a natural number?

Comment: It doesn't say but I think yes

Comment: This can't be answered as it stands.  With $p=5$, say, and $n=4$ we have $2^4=16\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ but of course $16$ is not congruent to $1\pmod {25}$.  On the the other hand with $d=20$ we have $2^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $2^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod {25}$.  There must be more information about the connection between $p,n,d$.

Comment: please copy the exercise litterally if this doesn't work.

Comment: @zxc Is this the full question? Perhaps posting the full question/exercise will allow us to aid you better, the other comments are correct in saying that one would need to know the relation between $p,n,d$.

Comment: I corrected my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $ d $ is the order of $ 2 $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_p $, let $ n $ be given such that $ 2^n = 1 $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_p $. We then have $ d|n $. Let $ n = dm $ for some $ m $, then in $ \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} $ we have that $ 2^n = 2^{dm} = (2^d)^m \neq 1 $ which implies  $ 2^d \neq 1 $.

The statement does not hold generally if $ d $ is an arbitrary natural number. For instance, we have $ 2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} $, $ 2^2 \neq 1 \pmod{9} $, but choosing $d = 6 $ we have that $ 2^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{9} $.